# How to get cell value from google spread sheet which in any language and current time of spread sheet in JAVA

Tags: java, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I need your help in following points.

1. I am trying to get cell content from google spread sheet which in korean, but  `cell.getInputValue()` showing me question mark (????), could any of you experts please let me know how can I get the cell value which is any other language than English.

The value inserting correct but when I retrieve it shows me ???.

2. the second point is I need to get current time of sheet which is not inserted in sheet using java code.
   If any one change the sheet timezone that it must return the time of changed timezone means the value of `=NOW()` in Java.

Please help me to implement these both functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @igor-artamonov, Could you please suggest me an answer? Without editing The Question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question,

I know it is *not for Both* but I got the answer for first point i.e. **`cell.getInputValue()` showing me question mark (????)**
I resolved this by changing my project encoding and response encoding which goes to jsp page by `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` before redirect to jsp page.

Now there second point is remaining, If there anyone who can answer this, Please help!